# Placement of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my code is below for a simple slider. I was wondering why it does not work when I move my jquery code to the bottom (before the )?-- it works when it is at the top I did some reading but everyone seems to preach placing it at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slide Panel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel">
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>Now you see me!</p>
        </div>
        <p class="slide"><div class="pull-me">Slide Up/Down</div></p>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you have the other script file [script.js] at the top and it is probably using jQuery so it is not loaded. Needs to be at the bottom with the others.

Comment: Hmm... where is _your_ code?

Answer (score 0):

Because your main script, script.js is put before the declaration of jquery. Your main script should be declared after jquery. You can put script.js under the jquery script tags at the bottom of the page and it will still work or you can put the jquery script tags on top of the script.js tag at the top of the page and it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the latest practice is to include the scripts at the bottom of the page.  ALL of them, including yours.  Your custom scripts should appear dead last so the public domain scripts on which it depends are loaded first.

```
<body>
    <stuff/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"/>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Even if you do it the right way, there's still a chance that dependencies won't load in the right order, which is why they invented [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).